# .htaccess is ignored

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

In my `.htaccess` file I have:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/example/public_html/error/404
```

But when an 404 error occurs, the default page shows up instead of `http://localhost/example/public_html/error/404`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try modify your host config and set

```
<Directory /path/to/your/directory>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```